# Retornar dados de 2 tabelas entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Tenho a seguinte tabela:
Movimentação
-movimentacaoId
-ClienteId
-ProdutoId

Quando eu selecionar um determinado cliente quero listar todas movimentações em que eles está juntamente com o produto. como eu chamaria isso dentro da controller?

isso foi o que pensei até agora.

```
    public ActionResult MovimentacaoCliente(int id)
    {
        int clienteid = 0;

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            Cliente cli = db.Cliente.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            clienteid = cli.Id;

            List<MovimentacaoVM> pedidos = db.Movimentacao.Where(x => x.ClienteId == clienteid).ToArray().Select(x => new MovimentacaoVM(x)).ToList();

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Minha Model Movimentação para voces entenderem:

```
public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }

public int ClienteId { get; set; }
public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
public string ProdutoNome { get; set; }
public string ClienteNome { get; set; }

public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }


[ForeignKey("ProdutoId")]
public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
```

Movimentação vm

```
public class MovimentacaoVM
{
public MovimentacaoVM()
{

}

public MovimentacaoVM(Movimentacao row)
{
    MovimentacaoId = row.MovimentacaoId;
    ClienteId = row.ClienteId;
    DataCriacao = row.DataCriacao;
    ProdutoId = row.ProdutoId;
    ClienteNome = row.ClienteNome;
    ProdutoNome = row.ProdutoNome;
}
[Key]
public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
public int ClienteId { get; set; }
public string ProdutoNome { get; set; }
public string ClienteNome { get; set; }
public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Produtos { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Cliente { get; set; }
```

Comment: Seria bom postar o model `Movimentacao` também. Porque se lá tiver uma propriedade de navegação, é só usar a propriedade, caso contrário teria que fazer um join.

Comment: sim eu postei agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então você quer listar todas as movimentações que um cliente fez e puxar todos os produtos dessas movimentações ?

Então você tem 2 relações uma n : n (de produtos para movimentações) e uma de 1 : n (cliente e movimentações).

Então o que eu faria,

Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // outras propriedades ...
    List<Movimentacao> Movimentacao { get; set; }  
}
```

Classe Movimentação

```
public class Movimentacao {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // outras propriedades ...

    public Int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    List<MovimentacaoProdutos> MovProdutos { get; set; }  
}
```

Classe MovimentacaoProdutos

```
public class MovimentacaoProdutos {
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public Produto Produto{ get; set; }
    public Movimentacao Movimentacao { get; set; }

    // outras propriedades ...  
}
```

Classe Produto

```
public class Produto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // outras propriedades ...

    List<MovimentacaoProdutos> MovProdutos { get; set; }  
}
```

E como eu faria a consulta

```
public ActionResult MovimentacaoCliente(int id)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        List<Movimentacao> movs = db.Movimentacao.Include(m => m.Cliente)
                          .Include(m => m.MovProdutos).ThenInclude(mp => mp.Produto)
                          .Where(m => m.ClienteId == id);

        // e assim você vai conseguir ter acesso ao cliente e aos produtos
        // desculpa se faltou alguma coisa, fiz agora de cabeça, mas a logica seria +/- essa.

        return View();
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Forte Abraço.